# How to click on an element present inside the span?

Tags: jquery, html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

How to click on an element which is written inside the span
Please find the screenshot which gives a clear idea

[image]

Please help me to understand how can I click that element

Comment: use the id of span as selector like `$("#spanid").html()` also it is better to post code in OP than an image

Comment: `$("#spanid .sdt-menubtn-main").click(function() {})` this would be a click function for the element you have marked in your screenshot

Comment: `$(#span-id  div').on('click',function(){....});`

Comment: `Div` cannot be a child of `span`

Answer (score 1):

From the HTML code which you have shared, it looks like span id's are might be dynamic i.e., id's will change at every operation. So it is not possible to use id as locator every time. You can use Xpath/CSS/JQuery as locator

**For Example:** If you want to click on div(first-child) in span(forth-child) as per your shared screen shot

```
     xpath: .//[@id='sdt-content']/div[2]/div[2]/span[4]/div[1]
     jQuery: $(".sdt-content div:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(4) div:nth-child(1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a Lot!!.... for all your comments 
From next time I will ask my questions with more clarity 
I come with this approach

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sdt-layout-panel sdt-nav-actions']/span[4]/div[@class='sdt-menubtn-main']")).click();

and.....its working!!....

Thank You